# NSURLConnection automatic direct connection if proxy.pac download fails

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an app that uses NSURLConnection to communicate with a web server. If I have the Automatic Proxy Configuration setting enabled and the URL in that setting points to an unavailable server, my NSURLConnection attempt will fail with a timeout error. If I make the request again, NSURLConnection will attempt a direct connection (it must note that the proxy failed) and the request succeeds.

I noticed that Safari will attempt the direct connection once the proxy times out as well but it does this automatically. I downloaded the latest WebKit nightly source, built it and attempted to figure out how this is done. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how WebKit gets this behavior. It creates an NSURLConnection but -connection:didFailWithError: never gets called. After the proxy times out, the -connection:didReceiveResponse: delegate gets called because it did a direct connection. Nothing in the WebKit code, that I can see, detects this proxy timeout and forces a reload. This must be happening in NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest.

How do I get NSURLConnection to automatically retry the direct connection on proxy failure? I want it to work exactly like it does in Safari/WebKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It had to do with the request timeout interval. The default timeout interval for NSURLRequest is 60 seconds. It was taking almost 90 seconds for the initial proxy timeout to occur so NSURLConnection wasn't falling back to the direct connection. Once I increased the timeout in the request, it started working.